# FTP Recoving! so i made a small perl script! but its so slow

Tags: perl

hey dude amigos im trying to recover my lost pass in my ftp server so i made a simple perl program to recover it!

but it seems very slow.. is there a way to speed this up???
and make this code works fine because after 5-9 pass attempts it stops,
it receive a timeout occured!!! plss help me...!`

```
#this is my code!
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my $host = '127.0.0.1';
my $user = 'amely';
my $dic = $ARGV[0];
open(FH, '<', $dic);
while(<$FH>){
chomp;
my $pass = $_;
my $log = $pass;
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host);
last if(
    $ftp->login($user, $log)
    );
    print "Trying: $_ [X]: Failed\n";
}
print "Pass Matched 100%: $_\n";
print <<EOF;
[       ftp://$ARGV[0]      ]
[   Username: $ARGV[1]  ]
[   Password: $_      ]
[   Good day for tuna   ]
```

thanks!...

Answer (score 1):

That timeout might be the FTP-server seeing an attempt to brute force a password and thus slowing it down. Which would slow down any attack attempting to break your password. While this is a good thing it of course also slows down your good attempts to break your own password, because they are indistinguishable from a bad attack.

Answer (score 0):

You have used:

```
last if(
    $ftp->login($user, $log)
    );
    print "Trying: $_ [X]: Failed\n";
}
```

i am just curious, why are you using `last if` even when you wants to iterate all the passwords present in the log file and one more point, you should disconnect the FTP connection after the works done. Replace above code with the code below:

```
if($ftp->login($user, $log)) {
    $ftp->disconnect; #Disconnect the current FTP connection
    next;
}
print "Trying: $_ [X]: Failed\n";
```